# Email Address Validation using apache poi excel creation

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am generating an excel(.xls) file using Apache POI Java. After Generating an excel , I want to validate for wrong email address Ids.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache commons Validator. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/

There is an API to just validate emails "EmailValidator.java"

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator;

boolean isValidEmail = EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid("kj@stacko.com");
```